# Why I am returning the wrong output?

Tags: java

I am not sure why I am returning false for the first test run as shown in the test table attachment. This was one of my assignments last semester and I never figured out how to solve it:/ My assignment was to:

Write the definition of a method , oddsMatchEvens, whose two parameters  are arrays  of integers  of equal  size. The size of each array  is an even number. The method  returns true  if and only if the even-indexed elements  of the first array  equal  the odd-indexed elements  of the second, in sequence. That is if w is the first array  and q the second array , `w[0]` equals `q[1]`, and `w[2]` equals `q[3]`, and so on.

Test table

[image]

My code was:

```
public boolean oddsMatchEvens(int[] w, int[] q) {
    int count = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < w.length; i++) {
        if (w[i] == q[i + 1])
            count++;

        if (count == (w.length - 1))
            return true;     
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: At some point your array, q, will be out of bounds. Your for loop need to go from `i = 0; i < w.length - 1; i++`

Comment: No, since he uses i<w.length, not i<=w.length

Comment: But he is accessing q at i + 1

Comment: Why should it return `true` in the first case? 2 != 92 and 5 != 155, so according to your algorithm it should be `false`

Comment: Off by one error. You want `w.length` equalities, not only `w.length - 1` since `w` is the shorter array. But as a hint: Returning `false` on the first inequality makes things a lot easier.

Comment: Oh yes, I didn't notice this

Answer (score 0):

```
if (count == (w.length - 1))
    return true;
```

This is wrong, since you have only w.length/2 indices which you have to compare.

You should just return false, if w[i] != q[i+1].

And you should increase i by 2, not by 1.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems with the code:
Firstly, it is clearly mentioned the two input arrays are of equal length and you have to compare them even index to odd index. So the corner case occurs when you are checking last item of first array with last+1 item of second array(which doesn't exist as arrays are of equal length.
Secondly, you have to check first array even with second array odd so increment should be i+=2 and not i++.
Correct code with optimization(if one check fails you can come out of loop):

```
public boolean oddsMatchEvens(int[] w, int[] q) {
    for (int i = 0; i < w.length-1; i+=2) {

         if (w[i] != q[i + 1])
            return false;
         else
            continue;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean oddsMatchEvens (int []w, int []q) {
    for (int j = 0; j < w.length-1; j+=2) {
        if (w [j] != q [j+1])
            return false;
            continue;
        }
            return true;
}
```

Comment: I recommend leaving an explanation in words as well as the code fix e.g. like Siddharth has done.